Cannot disable acceptNavigationRequest in PyQt6 (QWebEnginePage)
So my problem is that i have no idea why this function here does not disable user interaction:
class DummyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.first_navigation_allowed = True  # Flag für die erste Navigation

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame):
        return False

I was expecting it to block all navigation requests except the first one.
But unfortunately when i click on a CTA in the webview it redirects to the next page.
Does anybody know what the issue could be?
